# Reference a component after removing & re-adding React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I remove the component by toggling the boolean value (in this case 'someBooleanValue'), the component is removed as well as the reference in `formConfirmPassword`. When I re-add the component, the reference is gone which throws an error (as it should)

So basically, how would I go about fixing this so that I may remove and add the component without throwing an error?
The following code should clear the question:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const HomePage = () => {

  const formEmail = useRef('')
  const formPassword = useRef('')
  const formConfirmPassword = useRef('')

  return(
    <>

    <TextInput ref={formEmail} id="email" label="Email" variant="standard" />

    <TextField inputRef={formPassword} id="password" label="Password" variant="standard" type="password" />

    {
      someBooleanValue
      ?<TextField inputRef={formConfirmPassword} error={formPassword.current.value !== formConfirmPassword.current.value} helperText={formPassword.current.value !== formConfirmPassword.current.value ? 'Passwords do not match' : '' } id="confirm-password" label="Confirm Password" variant="standard" type="password" />
      :null
    }
    </>
  )

}
```

Comment: Can you include the error you are seeing in the console? Is your `formConfirmPassword` consumed anywhere else?

Comment: @AdamThomas it's basically a "Cannot read properties of null" error. When I remove the 'error' & 'helperText' attributes, the error goes away. So that's the only place !

Comment: Gotcha, I know why, give me a few mins to post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sort of chicken and egg situation. When you unmount the component, react sets `formConfirmPassword.current` to null. When you mount it again, it populates it -- **however crucially, this actually happens after it tries to access it to pass down in your `error` and `helperText` props.**

`refs` attached to components are only set once they already rendered -- at which point its too late as the code has errored since its null on the initial pass.

Your main problem here is refs aren't really suitable for what you are trying to do -- which is react to changes in the `formPassword` and `formConfirmPassword` values. You need to use state here instead so that the data sticks around when it unmounts. Also, this will ensure that when `formPassword` or `formConfirmPassword` changes your error/helpertext props will re-evaluate. **When a ref value changes, it doesnt trigger a rerender which means your `error` prop for example wont automatically recalculate as the user types if you use a ref**.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const HomePage = () => {

  const [formEmail, setFormEmail] =  useState('')
  const [formPassword, setFormPassword ] =  useState('')
  const [formConfirmPassword, setFormConfirmPassword] = useState('')

  return(
    <>

    <TextInput id="email" label="Email" variant="standard" onChange={(e) => setFormEmail(event.target.value) } value={formEmail}/>

    <TextField id="password" label="Password" variant="standard" type="password" onChange={(e) => setFormPassword(event.target.value) } value={formPassword}/>

    {
      someBooleanValue
      ?<TextField error={formPassword !== formConfirmPassword} helperText={formPassword !== formConfirmPassword ? 'Passwords do not match' : '' } id="confirm-password" label="Confirm Password" variant="standard" type="password"  onChange={(e) => setFormConfirmPassword(event.target.value) } value={formConfirmPassword}/>
      :null
    }
    </>
  )

}
```

Comment: I tried `useState` but I wanted to avoid using it (basically avoiding unnecessary rerenders, on typing ... ). Is there no other way ?

Comment: So this is a pretty complicated topic. If you want to avoid unnecessary rerenders, you cant use refs exactly like you did as that will also break -- you need the rerenders in order to get your prop values correct. Unless it becomes a problem -- you dont have an issue to fix. If it does become a problem, you likely really want to use an uncontrolled form lib like https://react-hook-form.com/ which uses a complex subscription mechanism to get around too many renders.

Comment: I'll add the react docs themselves say "Don’t optimize prematurely!" and this is usually sound advice generally speaking anyway. Introducing complexity early to fix problems you dont yet have tends to cause more headaches.